# How to read dynamic field length in .csv using Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a `csv` with the following content:

```
id001 , mail1@test.de  , mail2@test.de
id002 , mailxx@test.de , mailxx@test.de , mailxx@test.de, mailxx@test.de...
```

The `csv` has no static mail fields the list contains dynamically created mail addresses, is it possible to parse these in an array with spring batch?

Comment: Easily to make it using write a custom reader.

Comment: @nghia-do can you show a simple example of that?

Comment: I don't have now but I can build one for you when I back from work

Comment: This would be great!

Comment: You can also use BeanIO with SB integration

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom [`LineMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/LineMapper.html) for that. This interface gives you the raw string that was read from the file and allows you to parse it and map it to your domain object.

You did not share your target type, but I think a `line.split(",");` could work in your case: you assign the first token to an `id` and the remaining tokens to a list of emails.